# Chrome Browser not starting up in Automation Testing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, automation, ui-automation

I been troubleshooting a lot but still no luck. I confirmed all the JAR(s) + Selenium JARS for Maven Repository I've also confirmed the chrome driver version number with my chrome browser and I've also inserted correct pathway by doing System.setProperty line but still no luck here is my Eclipse code and also the Error log below also class is defined as shown my left side panel of the Eclipse of my folders please see that also:

```
package seleniumWebBrowsers;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class IntroSeleniumBrowswers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        //Invoking Browser
        //Chrome - ChromeDriver -->Methods
        //Firefox - FirefoxDriver -->methods
        
        System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver","\\Users\\Dilsh\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        

    }

}
```

Error Log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at Introduction/seleniumWebBrowsers.IntroSeleniumBrowswers.main(IntroSeleniumBrowswers.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 4 more
```

I've verified the failsafe JAR file it's already in the Maven repository located on left panel of my JAR files which has selenium as well for JARS. Also, pathway is correct as I've checked 3 times. I've also followed some youtube videos and online resources to try fix my issue but same result. Please help.

Left Side Panel of Eclipse folders:
[image: Left Side Panel of Eclipse folders please click here to see]

Comment: Does deleting your `module-info.java` file help (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_; see [here what `module-info.java` is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules))? If not, please show the command line used to run it (in the launch configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_ for that).